# AWS EKS load balancer service stuck at external-ip[pending]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-elb, aws-nlb

I am new to aws.

I am tryin to deploy my application to aws eks, everything is created well, except for my caddy server service, it stuck at pending status when it tries to get external-ip.

When I describe the service this is the output:

```
Name:                     caddy
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=caddy
Annotations:              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: instance
                          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
                          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
Selector:                 app=caddy
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.100.4.149
IPs:                      10.100.4.149
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31064/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.26.17:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               443/TCP
NodePort:                 https  30707/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.26.17:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age   From                Message
  ----     ------                ----  ----                -------
  Normal   EnsuringLoadBalancer  16m   service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Warning  FailedBuildModel      15m   service             Failed build model due to WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials
caused by: InvalidIdentityToken: Incorrect token audience
           status code: 400, request id: dd76289e-ca16-48e5-8985-3a4fc1b64f43
  Warning  FailedBuildModel  7m49s  service  Failed build model due to WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials
caused by: InvalidIdentityToken: Incorrect token audience
  status code: 400, request id: 62ed516f-c505-4bc8-979f-74edc449217e
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the problem was coming from the serviceAccount I have created, there was a a typo in the OIDC provider URI.